# jQuery Как удалить все option в select

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, веб-программирование

```
<select id="edit_adverestring_desc">
</select>
```

Для удаления старых `<option></option>` и добавления новых я использую следующий код:

```
$('#action_edit_adveresting').click(function(){ 
    $('edit_adverestring_desc > option').remove(); //удаление старых данных
    for (i = 0; i < gAdvertsingData.length; i++) //Добавление новых
            $('#edit_adverestring_desc').append('<option>' +
                                               gAdvertsingData[i].description + '</option>');
```

Проблема в том, что не удаляются старые `<option></option>` из списка.

Comment: что содержит `gAdvertsingData` ? вы хотите удалить все `<option></option>` и добавить новые ?

Comment: gAdvertsingData содержит инфу из базы данных. Да все верно.

Comment: Очепятка. Если вы указываете `$('edit_adverestring_desc > option')`, то вы обращаетесь к **элементу** (`<edit_adverestring_desc></edit_adverestring_desc >`), а такого не существует.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$('#action_edit_adveresting').click(function() {
  $('#edit_adverestring_desc').find('option').remove(); //удаление старых данных
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit_adverestring_desc">
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
  <option>test3</option>
</select>
<button id="action_edit_adveresting">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно очистить селект вот так:

```
$('#select_id').empty();
```